3D plot in R showing the relationship between the time, predictor and the hazard ratio
I found this online plotting the HR over time in a 3D plot
the person used codes from this website together with using the visreg2d function to get the HR, like written in this comment.
I'm sorry for providing links instead of showing the codes, but I have tried to study it for a long time and I'm still not sure how to do this, and what codes to use.
What I want is to plot my cox model in a 3D surface plot, showing the relationship between the predictor, time, and the hazard ratio. But how should I address this based on the examples I have referred to? I have a hard time using the examples to fit my data. So my cox model is build like this:
model <- coxph(
  Surv(start, end, outcome) ~ exposure + age + strata(gender)+offset(log(weight)), 
  robust = TRUE, 
  data = my_data
)

I'm interested in the covariate 'exposure' which is categorical , and its effect on the outcome also categorical, and I'm adjusting for age, which is continues.
what I have tried to do (and it's not working, already at the pam model), is the following:
pam <- gam(
  formula = outcome ~ te(end, exposure) + s(age),
  data   = my_data,
  family = poisson(),
  offset = offset(log(weight)))

##To plot the 3D plot with the anti-log HR. 
visreg2d(pam, x="exposure", 
   y=“end”, plot.type=“persp”, 
   theta=150,color=c(“blue”),
   trans=function(x){exp(x+my_intercept)})


